# spring mvc forward to jsp

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

I currently have my web.xml configured to catch 404s and send them to my spring controller which will perform a search given the original URL request.

The functionality is all there as far as the catch and search go, however the trouble begins to arise when I try to return a view.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver" p:order="1">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="jsp" value="text/html" />
        </map>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />

    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
            <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                <property name="suffix" value="" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
</bean>
```

This is a snippet from my MVC config file.

The problem lies in resolving the view's path to the `/WEB-INF/jsp/` directory. Using a logger in my JBoss setup, I can see that when I test this search controller by going to a non-existent page, the following occurs:

1. Server can't find the request
2. Request is sent to 404 error page (in this case my search controller)
3. Search controller performs search
4. Search controller returns view name (for this illustration, we'll assume `test.jsp` is returned)
5. Based off of server logger, I can see that `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView` is initialized once my search controller returns the view name (so I can assume it is being picked up correctly by the `InternalResourceViewResolver`)
6. Server attempts to return content to browser resulting in a 404!

A couple things confuse me about this:

1. I'm not 100% sure why this isn't resolving when `test.jsp` clearly exists under the `/WEB-INF/jsp/` directory.
2. Even if there was some other problem, why would this result in a 404? Shouldn't a 404 error page that results in another 404 theoretically create an infinite loop?

Thanks for any help or pointers!

Controller class [incomplete]:

```
@Controller
public class SiteMapController {

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
@Autowired(required=true)   
private SearchService search;

@Autowired(required=true)
private CatalogService catalog; 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/sitemap", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String sitemap (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {  
    String forwardPath = "";
    try {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000;
        String pathQuery = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");

        Scanner pathScanner = new Scanner(pathQuery).useDelimiter("\\/");
        String context = pathScanner.next();
        List<ProductLightDTO> results = new ArrayList<ProductLightDTO>();
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        String currentValue;
        while (pathScanner.hasNext()) {
            currentValue = pathScanner.next().toLowerCase();
            System.out.println(currentValue);
            if (query.length() > 0)
                query.append(" AND ");
            if (currentValue.contains("-")) {
                query.append("\"");
                query.append(currentValue.replace("-", " "));
                query.append("\"");
            }
            else {
                query.append(currentValue + "*");
            }
        }       

        //results.addAll(this.doSearch(query.toString()));

        System.out.println("Request: " + pathQuery);
        System.out.println("Built Query:" + query.toString());
        //System.out.println("Result size: " + results.size());     
        long totalTime = (System.nanoTime() / 1000000) - startTime;
        System.out.println("Total TTP: " + totalTime + "ms");

        if (results == null || results.size() == 0) {
            forwardPath = "home.jsp";
        }
        else if (results.size() == 1) {
            forwardPath = "product.jsp";
        }
        else {
            forwardPath = "category.jsp";
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }

    System.out.println("Returning view: " + forwardPath);
    return forwardPath;
}
}
```

Comment: In step 4, you said that you assumed the view name test.jsp was returned, but what exactly is returned. (see the log file)

Comment: I meant that based off of my logs and my visual std output verification it's actually returning either "home.jsp", "product.jsp", or "search.jsp", but for the above example I'm saying to assume that it returns "test.jsp"

Comment: Also what is the requested url and where exactly is the `test.jsp`? you need these three information to tell what goes wrong.

Comment: I already stated in #1 towards the end that "test.jsp" exists under "/WEB-INF/jsp/". Additionally I stated that this is a 404 catch, so any non-existent request goes here. But even calling the controller directly by going to "/dispatcher/sitemap.jsp" has the same behavior.

Comment: almost all unresolvable view name gives 404, it doesn't matter whether the controller is correctly handled or not.

Answer (score 2):

> 1 . I'm not 100% sure why this isn't resolving when test.jsp clearly exists under the /WEB-INF/jsp/ 
>   directory.

This is because you did configure your view resolver with `suffix = ""` so the file must be named `test` (no extension).

> 2 . Even if there was some other problem, why would this result in a 404? Shouldn't a 404 error page that 
>   results in another 404 theoretically create an infinite loop?

I'm pretty sure this's the result of some protection against the infinite redirect loop in spring MVC.

**Note:** in controllers, spring expect a view name as a result so `test` not `test.jsp` (or better, use `ModelAndView`)

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this as answer because it is too long but it is probably not an answer.

```
http://localhost:8080/webapp/servlet-mapping-url/controller-mapping/method-mapping
```

if your controller's method which handles the request does not return a view name string or a view object or write directly to output stream, spring dispatcher should resolve the view name to `/WEB-INF/jsp/controller-mapping/method-mapping.jsp`

This means the jsp must be under a folder, named  `/WEB-INF/jsp/controller-mapping/`. However, if a view name or view object is return by the controller method, spring dispatcher will uses that instead.

Ther are other many possible mapping combination but this is the most common one. If you could show your controller class, it will be easier.

**Update**

If you are using `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`, you should always annotated your class with `@RequestMapping(value = "/mapping-string")`. Otherwise spring dispatcher will try to pick it up when nothing else is matched.

Since the controller is mapped, you will have to change the method mapping to `value = {"", "/"}`

For the returning view name, you don't need to put `.jsp`.

If the returning view name is `home` then the spring dispatcher will resolve to `/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp`

If the returning view name is `path/home` then the spring dispatcher will resolve to `/WEB-INF/jsp/path/home.jsp`

P.S. You used a word forwardPath but it isn't really a forward. It is just a view name.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/sitemap")
public class SiteMapController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sitemap (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {  
            ...
            if (results == null || results.size() == 0) {
                forwardPath = "home";
            }
            else if (results.size() == 1) {
                forwardPath = "product";
            }
            else {
                forwardPath = "category";
            }
            ...
        return forwardPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: @jerluc I have updated the answer, let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: Returning the view name without .jsp just creates another 404 which re-invokes the controller. I'm going to try to see if i can just change the controller's extension to match something other than jsp in case maybe there's some confusion between a controller being matched and an actual jsp

Comment: did you access it through url/sitemap or url/sitemap/? the ending slash make it differen too.

Comment: I actually just found something very interesting..it seems that this behavior only appears in chrome, and yet when I view it in firefox, the view is returned as expected! I'm thinking maybe a difference in the `Accept` header?

Comment: Does chrome somehow have higher q value for json?

Comment: btw, does `url/sitemap` and `url/sitemap/` perform differently on firefox?

Comment: I don't use content negotiation. I request for `@RequestHeader(value = "User-Agent", required = false) String userAgent` and determine whether the request is coming from webbroswer or not.

Comment: This wouldn't be desirable given that nearly every browser may end up behaving completely differently. I'll need to find some other solution that will be independent of such a discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set order for your ViewResolver. For Example:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
  resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
  resolver.setOrder(1);
  return resolver;
}
```